# SQL Server stored procedure error (staff pay rise)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to do a stored procedure where I am giving staff a pay rise but i don't seem to understand what i am doing wrong, its giving me the following errors

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Procedure ClerkPayRise, Line 8
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

The code for my stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ClerkPayRise (@clerkID      VARCHAR (50),
                               @clerkPayrate DECIMAL(3, 2))
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE clerks
   SET clerkPayrate = clerkPayrate + @clerkPayrate
   WHERE clerkID = @clerkID

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        SELECT 'The Hourly Pay Rise for Clerk: ' + (SELECT clerkFName + ' ' + clerkSName
                                                    FROM   clerks
                                                    WHERE  clerkID = @clerkID) + 'Was Successful'
   ELSE
        SELECT ' The Increase in Hourely Pay rate Failed, No Clerk with ID ;   ' + CAST(@clerkID AS VARCHAR (50))
END

EXECUTE ClerkPayRise
  clerk01,
  0.25
GO

DROP PROCEDURE ClerkPayRise
```

Sample data I am using is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE clerks
(
     clerkID      VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
     clerkFName   VARCHAR (20),
     clerkSName   VARCHAR (20),
     clerkPayrate DECIMAL(3, 2),
     PRIMARY KEY (clerkID),
);

INSERT INTO clerks
VALUES ('clerk01' ,'Alex','Richards',7.49);

INSERT INTO clerks
VALUES ('clerk02', 'Jason','Elliot',8.25);

INSERT INTO clerks
VALUES ('clerk03', 'Mark','Alleyne',8.25);

INSERT INTO clerks
VALUES ('clerk04', 'Ricky','Ponting',8.00);

INSERT INTO clerks
VALUES ('clerk05', 'Nick','Lamb',8.75);
```

I will appreciate any guidance and help towards it

Comment: Works for me (once I add a "Role" column to the `clerks` table) and returns "The Hourly Pay Rise for Clerk: Alex RichardsWas Successful". Are you increasing someone to above `9.99`?

Comment: Your insert statement has more values than the columns.Please fix that.Also your solution works fine. Though you can find more details about your error here : http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-8115-numeric-to-varchar.aspx

Comment: Hi martin I have edited the table and insert statement please have a look, I am only looking to give staff a payrise of 0.25cents only looking to update the clerk pay rate column

Answer (score 0):

You have made some mistakes like

1. CREATE TABLE clerks (
   clerkID varchar (20) NOT NULL,
   clerkFName varchar (20),
   clerkSName varchar (20),
   clerkPayrate decimal(3,2),
   PRIMARY KEY (clerkID),
   );

In this query after "PRIMARY KEY (clerkID)" there should not be any comma ",".

2. You are assigning five values in a row but your table has only four       columns.

INSERT INTO clerks VALUES('clerk01','Mgr1', 'Alex', 'Richards',7.49);
This query is wrong . It is assigning five values instead of four

Please do the correction so that I can help you, if there are any problems in the stored procedure.

Comment: The trailing comma is permitted in a `CREATE TABLE` though not in a `DECLARE .. TABLE` - [relevant connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273348/trailing-comma-allowed-in-create-table)

Comment: Thanks Utlesh, I have edited the table and inset statement have a look now, i am only looking to upate the clerk payrate column nothing else, so by giving input parameters of clerk ID and the increase rate , i just wana update the pay rate of the employee for exmple if Alex Richards is getting 7.49$ he will get an increase of 0.25cents! hope that make sense

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `GO` batch terminator after the stored procedure body and the stored procedure execute statement.  This causes the `EXEC` statement to become part of the stored procedure so the stored proc then calls itself recursively until the arithmetic overflow occurs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ClerkPayRise (@clerkID      VARCHAR (50),
                               @clerkPayrate DECIMAL(3, 2))
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE clerks
   SET clerkPayrate = clerkPayrate + @clerkPayrate
   WHERE clerkID = @clerkID

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
        SELECT 'The Hourly Pay Rise for Clerk: ' + (SELECT clerkFName + ' ' + clerkSName
                                                    FROM   clerks
                                                    WHERE  clerkID = @clerkID) + 'Was Successful'
   ELSE
        SELECT ' The Increase in Hourely Pay rate Failed, No Clerk with ID ;   ' + CAST(@clerkID AS VARCHAR (50))
END
GO --need this terminator

EXECUTE ClerkPayRise
  'clerk01', --also enclose string literals in single quotes
  0.25
GO
```

Comment: That was removed by another editor. The code originally posted by the OP had a `drop proc` before the `exec` (which makes no sense at all) and I imagine would cause an error rather than a recursive call http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29333710/1